# PHP get value of multidimensional array and compair

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have this array `$pages` which spits out this data:

```
Array ( 
    [Name] => Array ( 
        [Subname] => Array ( 
            [0] => 43.2057, -79.9632, 1, -70,-150 
            [1] => 140240757658.jpg 
            [2] => 5 
            [3] => 0 
        ) ) 
    [Name2] => Array ( 
        [Subname2] => Array ( 
            [0] => 43.1769, -79.4703, 5, -70,-150 
            [1] => 140267498933.png 
            [2] => 16 
            [3] => 0 
        ) ) 
)
```

and I have this foreach setup:

```
foreach($pages as $row => $value) {
    echo '<li>'.$row.'<ul>';
    foreach($value as $x => $y) {
        echo 
            '<li>
                <a href="page.php?" action='.str_replace(" ", "", strtolower($y[2])).'" title="'.$x.'">'.$x.'</a>
             </li></ul></li>';
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is if [3] in each of the Subname is equal to 0, then skip it from my foreach.

NOTE: Subname and Name are just examples, they will be different for each one.

Comment: Shouldnt the `action`parameter be `page.php`? what is the use of the `action` in your anchor?

Comment: If both [3] are equal to zero skip them ?

Comment: if one of [3] are equal to zero, skip that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    foreach($page as $subname) {
        if ($subname[3] != 0) {
            /* Do whatever you want with the data of this subname */
        } 
    }
}
```

Or this if you want to use the key names:

```
foreach ($pages as $pageKey => $page) {
    foreach($page as $subnameKey => $subname) {
        if ($subname[3] != 0) {
            /* Do whatever you want with the data of this subname */
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: `if($subname[3] === 0) continue;` is going to be a much more efficient way of checking. It will check the value only once.

Comment: Why would it be more efficient? why would it check the value only once? The OP would then have to use an `else` in case the value is ≠ 0 am I wrong?.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip the sub-foreach then this is the solution

```
foreach($pages as $row => $value) {
    if($value['Subname'][3] == 0)
        continue;

    echo '<li>' . $row . '<ul>';
    foreach($value as $x => $y) {
        echo '<li><a href="page.php?action=' . str_replace(" ", "", strtolower($y[2])) . '" title="' . $x . '">' . $x  . '</a></li></ul></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: forgot to mention that Subname will be different

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an Associative Array you will not be able to to check

```
$pages['foo']['bar'][0] === 0
```

**before** the first `foreach` begins since we **don't know** the value of `$pages['foo']` before hand. when we get to the check you have already output html at the point in the form of:

```
 echo '<li>' . $row . '<ul>';
```